# Show that $R \cap R^*$ and $R \cup R^*$ are equivalence relations.

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be a reflexive and transitive relation on a set $S$. Let $R^*$ be the dual relation, $(a,b) \in R^*$ if and only if $(b,a) \in R$. Show that $R \cap R^*$ and $R \cup R^*$ are equivalence relations.

My attempt: By definition 6.2.3

R is reflexive if $(\forall x \in S)(b,b) \in R]$

R is transitive if $(\forall x, y, z \in S)[((b,a) \in R \land (a,c) \in R) \rightarrow (b,c) \in R]$.

At first I wanted to disprove the statement. I thought that R wouldn't be an equivalence relation because it was only reflexive and transitive, not symmetric. And by set intersection definition  for $R \cap R^*$ I thought that $R$ and $R^*$ must both be an equivalence relation . However for set union definition, $R$ or $R^*$ can be equivalence relation. It turns out that it's possible to prove.

I was given this massive hint during the lecture:

$(a,b) \in R^* \leftrightarrow (b,a) \in R$.

Set $T = R \cap R^*$. Show that $T$ is an equivalence relation.

1. $(a,a) \in R$ and $ (a,a) \in R^* \rightarrow (a,a) \in R \cap R^*$
2. Suppose $(a,b) \in R \cap R^* \rightarrow (a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R \rightarrow (b,a) \in R \cap R^*$
3. Suppose $(a,b) \in R \cap R^*$ and $(b,c) \in R \cap R^*$ then $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$. $(b,c) \in R)$ and $(c,b) \in R$. So $(a,c) \in R $ and $(c,a) \in R$. So $(a,c) \in R$ and $(a,c) \in R^*$ and $(a,c) \in R \cap R^*$

Is $R \cup R^*$ and equivalence relation?

$(a,b) \in R \cup R^*$ if $(a,b) \in R$ or $(b,a) \in R$.

$(a,b) \in R \cap R^*$ if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$

The first two work, but the last one won't match. give a counter example

I'm thinking that the last one won't match because we have the extra element c, but how do I show it. Do I let a,b,c be sets in $R$ and $R^*$ like let $A =[1,2],B = [1,2]$ and $C=[1,2,3]$? And then use the dual relation to see that something doesn't match due to the $3$ in $C$?

Answer (score 0):

The following rules are not to difficult to prove:

1) For every relation $R$ the relations $R\cap R^*$ and $R\cup R^*$ are symmetric.

2) If $R$ is transitive (reflective, symmetric) then $R^*$ transitive
(reflective,symmetric) .

3) If relations are reflexive then so is there intersection (union).

4) If relations are transitive then so is there intersection.

5) If relations are symmetric then so is there intersection (union).

Applying this shows easily that  $R\cap R^*$ is an equivalence relation
if $R$ is transitive and reflective, but it cannot be concluded that
$R\cup R^*$ is an equivalence relation.

As a counterexample take set $\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} $ with on it
the relation $\left(x,y\right)\in R\iff x\leq y\wedge\left(x,y\right)\ne\left(2,3\right)$. Then $R$ is reflexive and transitive, and $R\cup R^*=\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \times\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} -\left\{ \left(2,3\right),\left(3,2\right)\right\} $
. Then $\left(3,1\right)$ and $\left(1,2\right)$ belong to $R\cup R^*$ but
$\left(3,2\right)$ does not, so it is not transitive.

A proof of 1):

$$\left(a,b\right)\in R\cap R^{*}\iff\left(a,b\right)\in R\wedge\left(a,b\right)\in R^{*}\iff\left(b,a\right)\in R^{*}\wedge\left(b,a\right)\in R\iff\left(b,a\right)\in R\cap R^{*}$$

$$\left(a,b\right)\in R\cup R^{*}\iff\left(a,b\right)\in R\vee\left(a,b\right)\in R^{*}\iff\left(b,a\right)\in R^{*}\vee\left(b,a\right)\in R\iff\left(b,a\right)\in R\cup R^{*}$$

Comment: the $R \cup R^*$ is such an issue to me because I am thinking that by set union definition it's either $R$ being the equivalence relation or $R^*$ being the equivalence relation. But what I don't get is how symmetric is even possible since $R$ was only reflexive and transitive to begin with. Isn't it that equivalence relations need to be reflexive, transitive, and symmetric? Where is the symmetry?

Comment: will the transitive for $R^*$ be $(\forall x, y, z \in S)[((a,b) \in R \land (b,c) \in R) \rightarrow (a,c) \in R^*]$

Comment: Both relations $R\cup R^*$ and $R\cap R^*$ are symmetric (see edit). I don't understand what makes you think that either $R$ or $R^*$ is an equivalence relation. If $R$ is transitive, reflexive but not symmetric, then $R^*$ is transitive, reflexive but not symmetric. However their union and intersection both are symmetric.

Comment: on the previous post, I'm talking about the transitivity of  $R^*$ only since $(a,b) \in R^*$. Would the transitivity of $R^*$ be $(\forall x, y, z \in S)[((a,b) \in R \land (b,c) \in R) \rightarrow (a,c) \in R^*]$?

Comment: In the context of the title of your question it is irrelevant whether $R$ or $R^*$ is an equivalence relation or not. It's all about their union and intersection. In my answer it is proved that $R\cap R^*$ is indeed an equivalence relation under the condition that $R$ is reflexive and transitive, and secondly that $R\cup R^*$ is *not* necessarily an equivalence relation in that case.

Comment: so ok.for the proof of $(a,b) \in R \cap R^*$ for $R \cup R^*$ is it....

Comment: $(a,b) \in R \cap R^* \leftrightarrow (a,b) \in R \land (a,b) \in R^* \leftrightarrow (b,a) \in R* \land (b,a) \in R \leftrightarrow (b,a) \in R \cap R^* $

Comment: and then for the and part on the second sentence

$(a,b) \in R \cap R^* \leftrightarrow (a,b) \in R \land (a,b) \in R^* \leftrightarrow (b,a) \in R^* \land (b,a) \in R \leftrightarrow (b,a) \in (R \cap R^*) $? @drhab

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying in my answer and proves that the intersection is symmetric. For the union symmetry can be shown too.

Comment: and that's for the second sentence $(a,b) \in R \cap R^*$ if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$ ?!...the previous two comments that I've typed?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say here.

Comment: I'm trying to prove the second part of $ R \cup R^*$ which is $(a,b) \in R \cap R^*$ if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$from the hint that I was given @drhab

Comment: ah. I think I'm able to prove reflexivity for $R \cup R^*$ 
$(a,a) \in R \cap R^* \leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R \land (a,a) \in R^*$........$ \leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R \land (a,a) \in R^*$.........$\leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R \cap R^*$

Comment: $(a,a) \in R \cup R^* \leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R \lor (a,a) \in R^*$........$\leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R^* \lor (a,a) \in R$.........$ \leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R \cup R^*$ @drhab

Comment: Should it not be $(a,b)$ instead of $(a,a)$? If so then here you prove the symmetry of the union, and again it is exactly what I have written in my answer.

Comment: What the heck ? Then what do  I do for reflexivity? that's just one element.... I was trying to prove reflexivity...like.. argh that was a great idea in my head and went out just fast.... X______X @drhab

Comment: If $(a,a)\in R$ then it is immediately clear that $(a,a)\in R\cup R^*$. Simply because $R\subset R\cup R^*$.

Comment: so for reflexivity should I just put $(a,a) \in R \lor (a,a) \in R^* \leftrightarrow (a,a) \in R \cup R^*$ ?!?!?!?! @drhab

Comment: Think things over (e.g. the points 1),...,5) in my answer) and come back with a clear comment if you are ready with that. Your comments uptil now are too sloppy. I stop now, but will come back later.